# ansible fetch is not working as expected

Tags: ansible, yaml

On remote host I have many files under /tmp with name like EM_Prereq*, I want to copy all those to my ansible server under current ansible working directory or /tmp/results directory . 
I am using below code and is working fine but its creating files in different path than I expected.

ansbile creating file in path `/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt/test.host.com/tmp/<actual file name>`

But i want file to be created as `/tmp/results/<file name>`

`---
 - name: 'vij'
   hosts: 'all'
   gather_facts: 'false'
   tasks:
     - name: 'ls files'
       shell: "ls -l /tmp/EM_Prereq_*|awk '{print $(NF)}'"
       register: 'filetocopy'
     - name: 'fetch files'
       fetch :
         src: '{{ item }}'
         dest: '{{ item }}'
       with_items: '{{ filetocopy.stdout_lines }}'`

Output is below

`changed: [test.host.com] => (item=/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt) => {
    "changed": true,
    "checksum": "1f7edc7c9704add9f3b191c70a6eb81aa4ff3e14",
    "dest": "/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt/oc-129-158-67-48.compute.oraclecloud.com/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt",
    "item": "/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt",
    "md5sum": "de1bcca72d0c391f203d2956e672f51d",
    "remote_checksum": "1f7edc7c9704add9f3b191c70a6eb81aa4ff3e14",
    "remote_md5sum": null
}`

Appreciate your inputs

Comment: "*is not working as expected*" ― you set `dest: '{{ item }}'` ― how is that not expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fetch_module.html

You need: **flat: yes** as the documentation says: *Allows you to override the default behavior of appending hostname/path/to/file to the destination. If dest ends with '/', it will use the basename of the source file, similar to the copy module. Obviously this is only handy if the filenames are unique.*

```
 - name: 'fetch files'
   fetch :
     src: '{{ item }}'
     dest: '/tmp/results/'
     flat: yes
   with_items: '{{ filetocopy.stdout_lines }}'
```

edit: you also want '/tmp/results/' for the destination directory, and not {{ item }}